# Sum of three series with datetime index and different lengths?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have three series like:

Series 1:

```
Timestamp
2017-04-02    21666.45
2017-04-03    21666.45
2017-04-04    21666.45
2017-04-05    21666.45
2017-04-06    21666.45
Freq: D, Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

Series 2:

```
Timestamp
2017-04-02    9918.6
2017-04-03    9918.6
2017-04-04    9918.6
2017-04-05    9918.6
2017-04-06    9918.6
Freq: D, Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

Series 3:

```
Timestamp
    2017-04-02    9769.55
    2017-04-03    9769.55
    2017-04-04    9769.55
    2017-04-05    9769.55
    2017-04-06    9769.55
    2017-04-07    9769.55
    Freq: D, Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

But I am getting the sum by adding all the series till 2017-04-06 only as:

```
normal_sum['Price'] + peak_sum['Price'] + off_sum['Price']

Timestamp
2017-04-02    41354.6
2017-04-03    41354.6
2017-04-04    41354.6
2017-04-05    41354.6
2017-04-06    41354.6
2017-04-07    Nan
```

Expected output:

```
Timestamp
2017-04-02    41354.6
2017-04-03    41354.6
2017-04-04    41354.6
2017-04-05    41354.6
2017-04-06    41354.6
2017-04-07    9769.55
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can `.join` and `.fillna(0)` before adding.

Comment: Or `reduce(lambda l, r: l.add(r, fillna=0), (series1, series2, series3))` if you wish to avoid creating an intermediate dataframe.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko, Series 1 and series 2 does not have the time timestamp of 2017-04-07.

Comment: you can pass `how='outer'` kwarg to `join` to keep all timestamps irrespective of the order in which the arguments are passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html) with parameter `fill_value`:

```
df = normal_sum['Price'].add(peak_sum['Price'], fill_value=0)
                        .add(off_sum['Price'], fill_value=0)
print (df)
Timestamp
2017-04-02    41354.60
2017-04-03    41354.60
2017-04-04    41354.60
2017-04-05    41354.60
2017-04-06    41354.60
2017-04-07     9769.55
Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

A bit changed [Yakym Pirozhenko' s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45234149/sum-of-three-series-with-datetime-index-and-different-lengths/45234855#comment77434193_45234149):

```
from functools import reduce
cols = [normal_sum['Price'], peak_sum['Price'], off_sum['Price']]

df = reduce(lambda l, r: l.add(r, fill_value=0), cols)
print (df)
Timestamp
2017-04-02    41354.60
2017-04-03    41354.60
2017-04-04    41354.60
2017-04-05    41354.60
2017-04-06    41354.60
2017-04-07     9769.55
Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

In this cases I typically use [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), which takes care of joining the indexes:

```
df = pd.concat([normal_sum['Price'], peak_sum['Price'], off_sum['Price']],
                axis=1).sum(axis=1)
```